# xml layout not supporting all screens

Tags: android

My xml layout doesnt support all screen sizes , below is the xml layout. please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:paddingTop="10px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/formbg">


 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/label" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Question Title" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/entry" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

 </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:paddingRight="0px" > 

   <TextView android:id="@+id/pass" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Type Description" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/passentry" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="100px" 
              android:textColor="#000000"   
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
              />

   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/labelbounty" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Enter Amount  $" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="5px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
               />

     <EditText android:id="@+id/bounty" 
              android:numeric="decimal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />          


   </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">



   <TextView android:id="@+id/duedatelabel" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Due Date" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" />

  <Button android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
   android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:text="Select Due Date"/>

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">


     <TextView android:id="@+id/labelprimary" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Category" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/primarycategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/labelsecondary" 
              android:layout_width="120px" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Sub Category" 
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="12sp" 
              android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
               />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/secondarycategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/secondary_category"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingRight="5px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:paddingBottom="10px" 
    />              
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:paddingRight="10px" android:paddingLeft="10px">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="65px" 
    android:background="@drawable/add_attachment"
    >

    </Button>

    </LinearLayout>




     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  android:paddingRight="10px" android:paddingLeft="10px">


    <Button android:id="@+id/askNow" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="65px" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/postquestions"/>

    </LinearLayout>




    <SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:topOffset="50dip" android:layout_width="600px" android:layout_height="700px">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="65px" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"></Button>
        <LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/slider_bg" android:id="@+id/contentLayout"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center" 
                        >
        <Button android:id="@+id/asknew" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="65px" android:background="@drawable/ask_new_question"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/logout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="65px" android:background="@drawable/logout_big"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>


    <android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </android.view.SurfaceView>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you posted images of which screens it doesn't support and why. But a brief look at your layout leads me to this suggestion: Don't use absolute pixel measurements. Use "dp" instead of "px". Also, read the guide topic on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: what about the images, I can replace all he px to dp, but images how will i refer them.

Comment: what about the images, I can replace all he px to dp, but images how will i refer them. i have replaced everything with dp for one screen it doesnt show full screen in some ldpi and it shows full layout in hdpis. Can you please refer me a sample project for supporting mutilpel screens.

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the layout not working properly, along with an explanation of what is wrong. Then we can guide you to how to get the layout right for all screen resolutions. Your layout is extremely complex and without such an explanation, it would be very difficult for anyone to know what parts are behaving as you intend and what parts are not.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change all the places where you use `px` to `dp`.

WHen you use `dp`, which is short for "density independant pixels", your layout should support multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use dip which density independent pixels instead of px which are pixels